# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am really struggling to comprehend the following problem - could anyone give me some input on how to solve this? I am really at a dead end with this. When running the following code, I get this error:

http://pastebin.com/uXB5Kx4s

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include_once 'Swift-5.0.3/lib/swift_required.php';


if(isset($_POST['button'])) {


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $organisation = $_POST['organisation'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $rec_email = 'ben@bubbledesign.co.uk';

    $message = "Comments : " . $comments . "<br>" . "organisation: " . $organisation . "<br>" . "Phone Number: " . $number ;

    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
        ->setFrom($email)
        ->setTo($rec_email)
        ->setBody($comments);

    $result = $mailer->send($message);
}

?>
```

Comment: That sounds like invalid e-mail address in `$_POST['email']`.

Comment: That has fixed it, really stupid error on my end. Thank you so much

Comment: Cool. I've composed a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `Swift_RfcComplianceException` exception is thrown when you feed Swift Mailer with an invalid e-mail address (invalid as in "does not follow the syntax defined in the RFC document", not as in "the account does not exist"). This can happen in any field that requires e-mail addresses (sender, recipient, CC...).

Since you're accepting addresses from untrusted sources you need to ensure that your code can cope with this. That simplest way is to catch the exception:

```
try{
    // ...
}catch(Swift_RfcComplianceException $e){
    // Assume $_POST['email'] is invalid, abort processing, notify the user
}
```

... but, to be fully sure that the wrong address is exactly `$_POST['email']`, you can validate it beforehand:

```
if( !Swift_Validate::email($_POST['email']) ){
    // $_POST['email'] *is* invalid, abort processing, notify the user
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to check

```
if(!Swift_Validate::email($email))
            { 
                 $msg    = "Email is not valid";  
                 $status = "error";  
            }
            else
            {    
                //Create the Transport 
                $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.mandrillapp.com', 587)
                                  ->setUsername('nishrit@stalkbuylove.com')
                                 ->setPassword('Tks9tkeU5PZIqHU-UVSZLw');
                $mailer   = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
                //Create a message 
                $message  = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
                               ->setFrom(array('contact@stalkbuylove.com' => 'StalkBuyLove'))
                               ->setTo($to)
                              ->setBody($body, 'text/html');
                //Send the message 
                $result   = $mailer->send($message);
                if($result>0):
                     $msg    = "Email send successfully ";  
                     $status = "success";  
                else:
                    $msg    = "Error in send email. Please try again";  
                    $status = "error";  
                endif;
            }
            $array  = array("status"=>$status,'msg' => $msg); 
            return $array;
```